# Send Ajax request to Rails server in java

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new in rails. I want to send ajax request to rails server in java application.(no javascript, just java) So, I used 'urlconnection' to make request in java. It worked without error(complete 200), However, It didn't update view. So, I think that it need to set some header to send ajax request. If possible, please give some example. Thank you..

```
[In Java application] >> Send request
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/app/subaction"
String param1 = "choi";
String param2 = "jun";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s",param1, param2);
URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", charset);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/javascript");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Requestedasasd-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
urlConnection.connect();

OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), charset);
writer.write(query);
if(writer != null){
  writer.close();
}


[app_controller.rb]

 def subaction
   @choi = params[:param1]  
   @jun = params[:param2]

   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end

[subaction.js.erb]
$('#textcontainer').empty().append("<%= j render 'textcontainer'%>");



[_textcontainer.html.erb]
choi : <%= @choi %>
jun : <%= @jun %>


[app.html.erb]
<div id=textcontainer></div>
```

Comment: Can you give some explain about the difference between headers of ajax request and normal request ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Java language itself, but hopefully I can give you some ideas about Rails:

---

[**Endpoint**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint)

You must remember Rais is, by virtue of being based on the HTTP protocol, a [*stateless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) system - meaning it works by building & rendering *responses* to *requests*

You might know this already (its surprising how many people attribute Rails to "magic"). It means that you have to consider how the response is going to be rendered, and then displayed, on your front-end.

The way to do this in Rails is as follows:

> 1. Set up an "endpoint" in your routes / controller
> 2. Ensure you can send to the endpoint
> 3. Work with the response from the endpoint

---

**Setup**

It seems you have most of the above outlined - in that you can send data to your controller

In case you don't know how to do this, here's how you do it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :your_controller do
   collection do
      match :your_endpoint, via: [:get, :post] #-> domain.com/your_controller/your_endpoint
   end
end


#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def your_endpoint
      ...
   end
end
```

This is pretty straightforward - you're essentially creating a rudimentary API (which allows you to interact with the system with external applications)

The problem you *probably* have is the way you're connecting with - or indeed interacting with - the system you've created. More specifically, in how you're going to

---

## Ajax

I'm sorry - I don't have experience with native Java, but what I can explain is how you'd get ajax working with Rails:

[image]

**Logs**

Firstly, you need to make sure you can track the progress of the request. You mention you' getting a `200` response - you need to **track this in your logs**.

You can either do this by observing the Rails CMD, when it loads, you'll be able to see how it responds to your request, including any errors.

You should get a response from Rails without any errors. If this is the case, it will allow you to consider what

--

**Response**

Secondly, you need to then consider how you're catching the response from Rails. You're relying on javascript performing functionality after you initiate the request - do you have a way to append this to your Java DOM?

As mentioned, Rails is `stateless`, meaning it will only send the response to any request you send. This means that **you have to "catch" the response** & process it yourself.

This can only happen if you explicitly handle it in your Java back-end

--

[**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Thirdly, and most importantly, you need to consider the role of [**CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in your application. As you're using XHR to access the application, you'll likely trigger a problem with the CORS policy (which is defaulted to blocking any external-domain requests)

You'll want to use a gem called [`rack-CORS`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to grant XHR access to your endpoint:

```
#config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource 'app/subaction', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can I ask additional questions?? I set up endpoint and rack-CORS by following your help. However, there was same problem. And then, I compared headers between a request from rails and a request from java. What is important member for ajax request? Finally, How can I track the progress ? I checked the log in "development.rb" and Rails CMD. Is there some other way to track the progress?

Comment: Below is Rails CMD log.

Started POST "/app/subaction2" for 127.0.0.1 at [current time...]<br>
Processing by AppController#subaction2 as */*
 Parameters: {"param1"=>"choi", "param2"=>"jun"}
 Rendered app/_textcontainer2.html.erb (4.0ms)
 Rendered app/subaction2.js.erb (36.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 84ms (Views: 77.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)